# clearInterval() on navigation.push react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, intervals

I wrote some code to set an Interval on my `dealScreen`:

```
let timer;
  useEffect(() => {
        timer = setInterval(() => { 
          console.log('test');
        }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }, []);
```

When navigating to another page with `navigation.push` the Interval isn't cleared.
How can I force the interval to be cleared on `navigation`. Because it is a stack so I think the page is still behind the new page.

When using `navigation.replace` it works but then I have no correct history back.

Comment: It's normal precdure, when you push new screen the previous will persist on the memory (will not unmount) but when you replace the screen the previous will unmount (clearInterval will execute) so you can easily clearInterval before push to other screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call the **clearInterval(timer)** function when you trying to navigate.

Example:

```
  let timer;
  useEffect(() => {
    timer = setInterval(() => {
      console.log('test');
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  const navigateToNextScreen = () => {
    clearInterval(timer);
    navigation.push('Next Sreen');
  };
```

I hope this help you out. Thanks.

Comment: This solution is not good, on every rerender the timer gets initialized to undefined, so it sill probably not work

Comment: I already found out this is a working solution but then I have to add this to all my links navigating from my `dealScreen`. I am using a header and footer as components. The `clearInterval` should be a global variable then.